# Show results from SQL Server procedure call in Excel Message Box

Tags: sql-server, vba, excel, stored-procedures

I have a VBA sub in Excel.  It needs to call a SQL Server procedure, and display the results of the call in a message box.  (Mainly, because I'm maintaining someone else's code - otherwise, I wouldn't be using Excel.)

I create my SQL statement to call the procedure.  I have subs that open the connection.  But I'm still missing something in the process of showing the results of that procedure call.

Here's what I have so far:

```
Dim Today As Date
Dim result As Date
Dim sSQLStatement As String
Dim strDate As String
Dim Recordset As ADODB.Recordset

Today = DateTime.Now()

result = DateSerial(Year(Today), Month(Today) - 1, 1)
strDate = Year(result) & "-" & Format(Month(result), "00") & "-" & Format(Day(result), "00")

DBOpen

sSQLStatement = "set nocount on; EXEC [MySchema].[dbo].[MyProcedure] @END_DATE = N'" & strDate & "'"

MsgBox sSQLStatement

Dim i As Long
Dim Ary
Dim strMsg As String

Set Recordset = New ADODB.Recordset
With Recordset
    .ActiveConnection = cnPubs 'this is defined elsewhere, used in the DBOpen call, and works

    'I can call the execute and it works, but it fails here when I try to assign the results to the recordset
     Recordset = cnPubs.Execute(sSQLStatement)

     'I found this online and don't know yet if it works.  I have to get past the statement above first.
     If Not Recordset.EOF Then
          Ary = Recordset.GetRows
          For i = 0 To UBound(Ary, 2)
              If i = 0 Then
                  strMsg = Ary(0, i)
              Else
                  strMsg = strMsg & ", " & Ary(0, i)
              End If
          Next i
          MsgBox strMsg, , UBound(Ary, 2) + 1 & " records"
     End If
     .Close
End With

DBClose
```

So, if I call the cnPubs.Execute(sSQLStatement) by itself, I can tell it is running.  I open and close the connection just fine.  But it should be returning a set of several rows, and I need to display that.  I don't want to write those to the spreadsheet anywhere - they should just be displayed in a message box.

Comment: if you put a break point on the line right after it calls GetRows, how many records are there?

Comment: It doesn't get that far.  Although, if I remove the 'Recordset =' from the line above... I'll give that a try.

Comment: put a break point on the recordset= line and tell me what the sSQLStatement variable says (you can print it to your debug window)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
Recordset = cnPubs.Execute(sSQLStatement)
```

to

```
recordset.open sSQLStatement, cnPubs
```

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you!  I now need to format the output better than what I have, but that's simple now that I have output.